# Qt Client Programming

Tags: qt, client

I wrote this program for a client on Qt but its not compiling. Errors as given after program.

Can someone help me out?

**MyClient.h:**

```
//MyClient.h
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <QObject>

class QTcpSocket;

class Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Client(QObject *parent = 0);
    void connectToServer();
signals:

public slots:
    void on_connected();
private:
    QTcpSocket* socket;
};

#endif // CLIENT_H
```

**MyClient.cpp:**

```
//MyClient.cpp
#include "MyClient.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include <QtNetwork/QHostAddress>
#include <cstdio>
#include<cstring>
Client::Client(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()),
            this, SLOT(on_connected()));
}

void Client::on_connected()
{
    printf("Connection established.\n");
    char buffer[1024];
    forever
    {
        printf(">> ");
        gets(buffer);
        int len = strlen(buffer);
        buffer[len] = '\n';
        buffer[len+1] = '\0';
        socket->write(buffer);
        socket->flush();
    }
}

void Client::connectToServer()
{
    socket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 1234);
}
```

**main**

```
//main
#include "tcpclient.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "MyClient.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Client c;
    c.connectToServer();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Errors:**

```
MyClient.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QTcpSocket::QTcpSocket(class QObject *)" (__imp_??0QTcpSocket@@QAE@PAVQObject@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Client::Client(class QObject *)" (??0Client@@QAE@PAVQObject@@@Z)

MyClient.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QTcpSocket::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QTcpSocket@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)

MyClient.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QTcpSocket::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QTcpSocket@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)

MyClient.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QTcpSocket::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QTcpSocket@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)

MyClient.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QAbstractSocket::isSequential(void)const " (?isSequential@QAbstractSocket@@UBE_NXZ)

MyClient.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall QAbstractSocket::close(void)" (?close@QAbstractSocket@@UAEXXZ)

MyClient.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QAbstractSocket::atEnd(void)const " (?atEnd@QAbstractSocket@@UBE_NXZ)

MyClient.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __int64 __thiscall QAbstractSocket::bytesAvailable(void)const " (?bytesAvailable@QAbstractSocket@@UBE_JXZ)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link with network  module, so you need to add *QT += network* in your project file, then *run qmake* and build.